# Webcomic about a priest on a pilgrimage and his guardians, which emulates an 8 bit rpg

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

I can't find a webcomic I use to read now.  It was written to emulate an 8 bit RPG, including playing out battles by showing the 'gamer' picking which action to take and having a picture of the box the cartridge supposedly came in etc.

The story was set in a world with four distinct races.  One primarily religious/lawful race included the equivalent of a priest who is going on a pilgrimage and so has talked some individuals into joining him as guardians.  His teammates include:

- A Bard from the 'fire' sect of the more magical race.
- A Warrior from the physical race, who was related by adoption to the bard and looks out for him.
- A Technologist/machinist who was friends with the bard and begrudgingly joined the pilgrimage out of a promise that the cost of making his robots would be covered while he was a guard.
- A Rouge from the same 'fire' sect as bard who is convinced to join shortly into the story and wants revenge on the leader of another sect who conquered/subjected the fire sect.

It was once in the top 100 gaming web comics list from topwebcomics.com but I haven't been able to find it there when I look now.

Comment: http://www.nuklearpower.com/2001/03/02/episode-001-were-going-where/?

Answer (score 2):

Do you maybe mean [8-Bit Theater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8-Bit_Theater)?

[image: 8-bit theater cast]

I honestly don't know much about the plot, but know it has always been a "well respected" Final Fantasy/gaming/D&D parody.

Comment: While a reasonable thought, there's no priest, no pilgrimage, and no outside person playing the game. RPG World has the last, but not the priest or pilgrimage, and was done in an anime-esque style with FF7-type dialogs.